# Is it possible to remotely control a computer from a virtual machine inside the controlled computer?

Tags: recursion, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

This is the scenario of my question: I have a computer A, with Windows 8 as SO. I installed virtualbox inside A, and create a virtual machine B with Windows 8 as SO, too. Then, in both computers (A and B) I installed Teamviewer and then I control computer A from virtual machine B. Is this scenario possible? Will the virtual machine B collapse because the infinite loop? Is this scenario useful for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create RDP from A to B and B to A recursively, till there is available memory to run that application. When there is no more memory to run this program it will display Out of Memory Error.

Here is a blog... Just go through it. http://www.reddit.com/r/geek/comments/q2oib/teamviewer_makes_it_pretty_easy_to_create_an/  http://www.virtualmore.org/blog/?tag=teamviewer